# "unexpected tokens following preprocessor directive - expected a newline"

Tags: c++, token, newline

I created this program, and for some reason Visual Studio is giving this 'warning'("unexpected tokens following preprocessor directive - expected a newline") whilst also finding errors that seem to reference the contents one line down from the line the compiler claims they're on. For instant, error [Carat Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqRlp.png) seems to refer to something only applicable [one line down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lz4hW.png). Thus, I believe something must have gone horribly wrong in the header of the program, but am unsure.Here is the code:

```
    //1/4/2017

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib> 


using namespace std;

void getNewItem();
void displayItems();
void displayRand();
vector<string> vecItems;

int main()
{
    //declaration phase

    int intInput;
    string strNewItem;


    cout << "Random Item Generator" << endl << "Written by #XXXXX" << endl << "1. Add Item" << endl << "2. Display All Items " << endl << "3. Display Random Item" << endl << "4. Quit" << endl;
    while (intInput != 4)
    {
        cin >> intInput;
        switch (intInput)
        {
        case 1:
            getNewItem();
            break;

        case 2:
            displayItems();
            break;

        case 3:
            displayRand();
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void getNewItem() {
    string strNewItem;
    cin >> strNewItem;
    vecItems.push_back(strNewItem);
}

void displayItems() {
    for (int i = 0; i < vecItems.size(); i++) {
        cout << vecItems.at(i) << endl;
    }
}

void displayRand() {
    int intRandIndex;
    //random number generator
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    intRandIndex = rand() % 10;

    cout << vecItems.at(intRandIndex) << endl;
}
```

Screenshot 1

[image: Screenshot 1]

Screenshot 2

[image: Screenshot 2]

EDIT: Visual Studio version is Visual Studio 2015, and I have both recompiled and ran in entirely new projects to no avail.

Comment: The sample given doesn't reproduce this error with Visual Studio 2015 or Visual Studio 2010. What version of Visual Studio are you using? Are you sure this is the example you meant to give?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 15, and have recompiled the program and remade it from scratch only to get the same issue :/

Comment: Perhaps the issue lies in your precompiled header. I had to exclude the line `#include "stdafx.h"` to compile (I do not have this header).

Comment: My compiler requires it, and won't run unless it is present. It's also never created a problem for me before

Comment: Try to delete the line that is causing the error, along with the previous and following line, then retype them (do not copy/paste them). I have encountered a problem once where an non displayable character caused a compiler error.

Comment: The error message in the title appears nowhere in your error output. This will completely confuse future users of this site.

Comment: Hmm... try opening the file up in Notepad, maybe that line has a *nix newline (LF) instead of a Windows newline (CR + LF); Notepad has trouble displaying LF newlines, so lines 17 & 18 will be mashed together if this is the case.  I wouldn't expect it to have a problem with that, but it's possible.

Comment: Thank you @FrançoisAndrieux and everyone else who replied! The fix of retyping worked, and the program now functions fine.

Answer (score 0):

the problem as I guess if some compiler warning settings which in vs 2015 by default prevents using UN-initialiazed variables so initialize intInput before using it:

```
int intInput = 0;
```